# GraphicsAdapter.Adapters on openGL won`t return secondary monitor

Tags: opengl, xna, monogame, cross-platform

I have been searching for this everywhere and never found the answer.

I am developing a feature to allow the user to select which monitor to run the game.

I have two monitors, primary and secondary. I tried to use "GraphicsAdapter.Adapters" but it always retrieves only 1 monitor (the one I am running the Visual Studio which is the default one).

Is this a bug?
How can I retrieve all the monitors available?

Thanks

MONOGAME 3.6 OPENGL (cross platform)
Visual Studio 2015
Windows 10 Pro 64bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at [the code for the 3.6 release](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/tree/1c09add4a7407cf14690614d5ec36666d6c2a8ea):

There are three files containing `GraphicsAdapter` source code. It looks like [`GraphicsAdapter.Legacy.cs` is used if you are using the Windows/OpenGL build](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/6b9c9ef8523e2b757b43ee7f943ee4e8f0c8b51e/Build/Projects/MonoGame.Framework.definition#L597) of MonoGame.

In this version of the code, [the `Adapters` property](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/1c09add4a7407cf14690614d5ec36666d6c2a8ea/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/GraphicsAdapter.Legacy.cs#L128) performs lazy-initialization of the underlying `_adapters` array. It has preprocessor blocks to build the array differently based on which platform is being built for. Since you're using Windows, that translates to a call to [this line](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/1c09add4a7407cf14690614d5ec36666d6c2a8ea/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/GraphicsAdapter.Legacy.cs#L145):

```
_adapters = new ReadOnlyCollection<GraphicsAdapter>(new[] { new GraphicsAdapter() });
```

The property then simply returns `_adapters`.

So yes, for OpenGL builds on Windows, `GraphicsAdapter.Adapters` will only ever return a single item. MonoGame does not appear to implement the functionality necessary to expose multiple-monitor support for OpenGL on Windows, at least not in the fashion you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for this useful information, Josh. Now I know where to head to. I dont have enough reputation to vote up yet but the vote was recorded! You will get it as soon as my rep increases it